# How to watermark a animated GIF in Android

Tags: java, android, gif, image-manipulation, animated-gif

Given an animated gif file in Android (Java), how can I add a watermark to it? (adding a semi-transparent image over the gif or adding a extra bar at the bottom/top of the gif)